# When i enter 1 it does the functions but does not loop. When i enter 2 it does the functions and loops. Why does the first one not loop back?

Tags: python, loops

#create a program that will act as a number convertor. This program will convert an input decimal integer into binary and hexadecimal formats.

#functions
#create a program that will act as a number convertor. This program will convert an input decimal integer into binary and hexadecimal formats.

```
def Decimaltobianry(Decimal):
    print("Converted to binary " + bin(Decimal))

def Decimaltohex(Decimal):
    print("Converted to hexadecimal " + hex(Decimal))

def numberConverter():
    condition=1
    while condition==1:
        print("1. Converting a decimal number to binary")
        print("2. Converting a decimal number to hexadecimal")
        print("3. Exit the program")
        print("")
        Options=str(input("Select one of the options"))
#if statements
        if(Options==("1")):
            Decimal=int(input("Enter a number from 1 to 1000"))
            print("")
            if Decimal in range(1, 1001):
                print("The decimal number " + str(Decimal) + " is in range ")
                Decimaltobianry(Decimal)
                print("")
            else:
                print("The decimal number entered is outside the given range. Choose your options again!.")
                print("")
        if (Options == ("2")):
            Decimal = int(input("Enter a number from 1 to 1000"))
            print("")
            if Decimal in range(1, 1001):
                print("The decimal number " + str(Decimal) + " is in range ")
                Decimaltohex(Decimal)
                print("")
            else:
                print("The decimal number entered is outside the given range. Choose your options again!.")
                print("")
        else:
            print("End of Program!")
            break




numberConverter()
```

Comment: Might want to make the second if options an elif.

Comment: Your a genius. Thank you!

Comment: Np upvote the comment.